# When does the compiler use the actual character of a string and when does it use it's ASCII value?

Tags: c

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

int myAtoi(char * str);

int main()
{
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);

    char* string;

    string = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", string);

    int ans;
    ans = myAtoi(string);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}

int myAtoi(char* str)
{
    int num = 0, negative = 0;

    int l = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
        if (str[0] == '+' || str[0] == '-' || str[0] == ' ' || (str[0] >= 48 && str[0] <= 57))
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
                continue;

            if (str[i] == '-')
            {
                negative = 1;
                continue;
            }

            if (str[i] == '+')
            {
                negative = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if (str[i] >= 48 && str[i] <= 57)
            {
                num = num + str[i];

                if (i != l - 1)
                    num = num * 10;
                continue;
            }
        }

        else
            return 0;
    }

    if (negative == 1)
        return (-1 * num);

    else
        return num;
}
```

The point of my doubt is:

```
if(str[i] >= 48  && str[i] <= 57)
{
    num = num + str[i];

    if(i != l - 1)
        num = num * 10;
    continue;
}
```

I want to know that when does the compiler  use the actual value of the character str[i] and when does it use the ASCII value. Here str[i] is always being replaced by the ASCII value, resulting in the wrong answer.

Please elaborate the concept behind all this i.e. the ASCII codes and strings & characters.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A character's "value" is it's ASCII value (unless the system uses something else than ASCII for encoding).

Comment: `if(str[i] >= 48  && str[i] <= 57)` is equivalent to saying `if(str[i] >= '0'  && str[i] <= '9')`, if that helps.  The compiler will substitute '0' and '9' with the integer values 48 and 57 and compile time.

Comment: In other words `'0'` is the ASCII *character-literal* that has the value of `48`. See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/). But note, there are those rare odd machines that use something other than ASCII (not nearly as common as it was 40 years ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if(str[i] >= 48  && str[i] <= 57)
{
    num = num + str[i];

    if(i != l - 1)
        num = num * 10;
    continue;
}
```

You probably meant:

```
if(str[i] >= '0'  && str[i] <= '9')
{
    int digit = str[i] - '0';    // convert ascii character for a digit to its actual numberic value (0-9)
    num = number * 10 + digit;
    continue;
}
```

I substituted '0' for 48 and '9' for 57. The compiler interprets character literals as their ascii value.  So for readabilitiy, just use the character literal instead of the ascii value.

I don't under that `if(i != l - 1)` expression or what it serves. You do want to include the last character in the string as part of the number, right?

Comment: Thank You, sir. Yes, you're right. If I reach the end of the string, it means that i don't have to multiply num with 10.

Comment: Detail: C defines `'0'` as a _constant_, not _literal_.

Comment: @TanishSharma - you absolutely do have to multiply `num` by 10 when you reach the end of the string.  Each digit you read should result in `num = num*10+digit` being computed.

Answer (score 0):

The actual value of the character str[i] is the ASCII.

You can fix your code by add `- '0';` in the following line.

```
num = num + (str[i] - '0');
```

For example, ASCII '1' is 49 and ASCII '0' is 48.

So if str[i] is '3' then you can can integer value 3 from it by doing

`str[i] - '0';`

Answer (score -1):

whenever there is a conversion of character to integer ASCII value is used and as strings are of character type therefore their ASCII value is used here